# Google Ads - Wrong Category

Tags: google-ads-api

Google wrongly assumes that our page is related to online gambling and therefore disapprove our ads. But we don't see any option to disagree with this categorization. Do you guys have any ideas? We couldn't find any information.

[image: Screen disapproved]

Answer (score 0):

Change the structure of your ads and reput it on this time Google will accept ur add